# Print values of StringArray from java class into JSP

Tags: java, jsp, data-structures

I have a form class where I have a String array. I am setting the value for the string array. I need to print this array values one by one in a JSP page. The code I have written is:

```
paxList = getPaxList(id);

List<String> passengerName = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> passengerAge = new ArrayList<Double>();

for(int i=0; i < paxList.size(); i++){
    passengerName.add(paxList.get(i).getPassengerName());
    passengerAge.add(paxList.get(i).getPassengerAge());
}

bookingsForm.setPassengerName(passengerName.toArray(new String[paxList.size()]));
bookingsForm.setPassengerAge(passengerAge.toArray(new Double[paxList.size()]));
```

Now I need to print the values from the `PassengerName`.

I tried like this in my JSP page

```
<logic:iterate id="currentPassName" property="passengerName" >
    <bean:write name="currentPassName" />
</logic:iterate>
```

but this is not working for me. can someone guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't split your list of passengers into two lists of name and age. That's what makes things difficult. Just store `paxList` into your form directly.

Once this is done, do yourself a favor and use the JSTL rather than the deprecated struts logic and bean tags:

```
<c:forEach items="${bookingsForm.paxList}" var="passenger">
    Passenger <c:out value="${passenger.name}" is aged ${passenger.age}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

To explain why it doesn't work as is:

```
<logic:iterate id="passRecord" property="passengerName" >
    <bean:write name="passengerName" property="passRecord" />
</logic:iterate>
```

The above iterates through the elements of the form's `passengerName` array (which you should name `passengerNames`, since there are several of them), and defines a page attribute named `passRecord` that you must use inside the loop.

Since `passengerName` is a String array, `passRecord` is a String. And inside the loop you're trying to access the property `passRecord` of `passengerName`. There is no method `getPassRecord()` in `String[]`. The passenger name is stored in `passRecord`. You just need to write it. With properly named variables, it would be much clearer:

```
<logic:iterate id="currentPassengerName" property="passengerNames" >
    <bean:write name="currentPassengerName" />
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: @ Nizet, i can't use JSTL here. My scenerio is bit complicated now. I should provide a input field for passenger name if there is no record and if there is a record then it should be written into the same field. I'm tried this way

Comment: <logic:notEmpty name="passRecord" property="passengerList"> 
<logic:iterate id="passRecord" property="passengerList" type="com.abhibus.oprs.pojo.booking.PassengerInformation" >
<bean:write name="passRecord" property="passengerName" > </logic:iterate>
</logic:notEmpty>                                       <logic:empty name="passRecord" property="passengerList">            <input type="text" name="passengerName" id="passengerName<%= (RequestType + i) %>" maxlength="150" size="15" class="requiredfield"/>
</logic:empty> but still not able to find the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

With jstl you could do it somethign like this :

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var = "oneName" items = "${passengerName}" >
    <tr><td> ${oneName}</td</tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```